# Importing CSV file into phpmyadmin that contains html

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom database that I exported as a CSV. I rearranged the columns and data to match the columns of a Wordpress database, so I could import the data.

The only problem is that one of the columns from the custom database includes HTML. This is stopping the data from being imported into Wordpress as a CSV. Is there any way to get around this? I really need to keep the HTML as I don't want to have to restyle hundreds of rows again.

It's taken a while to get the data into a format to manipulate in the first place.

p.s If I import the data without the HTML column it imports into Wordpress fine.

Here's an example:

```
ID,post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_content_filtered,post_parent,guid,menu_order,post_type,post_mime_type,comment_count
5000,1,28/02/2012 15:00,28/02/2012 15:00,"<p>Marriott Royal Hotel, College Green, Bristol<br />
<br />
We are pleased to announce the launch of the <a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.inets-sw.co.uk/default.aspx?page=495"">Microelectronics iNet</a> for the South West. This &pound;2.3 million ERDF funded project will facilitate innovation and growth across the microelectronics industry by working with businesses to transform exciting ideas into new products and services.</p>
<p>Join us for the opportunity to learn more about the iNet and to hear leading technology entrepreneur Professor David May speaking on future trends and opportunities.</p>
<p>Speaking alongside Professor May will be Rick Chapman, Director of the Microelectronics iNet and Nick Sturge, Director of the SETsquared Business Acceleration Centre in Bristol.</p>
<p>Please register by Friday 26 November.</p>
<p><a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.inets-sw.co.uk/micro/events/december_200/ingenious_britain_in_action.aspx"">Further details</a> or <a target=""_blank"" rel=""nofollow"" href=""https://www.formstack.com/forms/inets-launch"">book now</a></p>
<p>About the iNets<br />
The Microelectronics iNet is a consortium of universities, commercial organisations and industry networks. The project is led by the University of the West of England, and includes the University of Bristol, STMicroelectronics, the National Microelectronics Institute and the Electronics, Sensors and Photonics KTN.<br />
<br />
Agenda<br />
16:00 Arrival<br />
16:30 Welcome &amp; Introduction<br />
16:45 Professor David May<br />
17:30 Rick Chapman<br />
17:50 Nick Sturge<br />
18:30 Drinks and canap&eacute;s</p>
<p>Get updates<br />
<a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""https://www.formstack.com/forms/inets-mailing_list"">Sign up</a> to receive regular updates from the Microelectronics iNet</p>
<p>Contact Us<br />
0117 32 86690<br />
<a href=""mailto:microelectronics@inets-sw.co.uk"">microelectronics@inets-sw.co.uk</a><br />
<a rel=""nofollow"" target=""_blank"" href=""http://www.inets-sw.co.uk/"">http://www.inets-sw.co.uk/</a></p>",Microelectronics iNet Launch,,publish,closed,closed,,,,,11/04/2012 10:04,11/04/2012 10:04,,0,http://www.mediwales.com/v3/?post_type=tribe_events&#038;p=5000,0,tribe_events,,0
```

Comment: What are you using for the data import? any application or something like phpMyAdmin....

Comment: @SandeepRajoria Yep, that exactly - phpmyadmin.

Comment: well you will have to edit the csv to escape the html characters...something like php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php or export the db in sql if you can....cos I couldnt find anything in phpMyAdmin for your scenario

Comment: @SandeepRajoria CSV is the only way to do it, as all the other methods were difficult to manipulate the data into the right fields.

Comment: try EMSMyManager it has options to import csvs, excels....data from many other formats...get the trial version and use it just for this once...I think that will solve your problem

Comment: can you pass me one of the rows(typical with html and stuff) may be after looking at it I can help...

Comment: @SandeepRajoria Thanks, just added the first row in the question. There's literally hundreds of rows similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in the csv file find replace

replace `'` with `\'`                \\will escape single quotes in the file

then
replace

`"<p>` with `'<p>`          \\ to put the text field in single quotes

and  then replace

`</p>"` with `</p>'`        \\ to put the text field in single quotes

and then try importing.... it should work

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting an error. Should I find and replace all " with ' ?

Comment: no no not all but only the beginning and the end...so that for mysql treats the whole thing as one..

Comment: I tried what I suggested before you got back and it seemed to work. Just double checking everything.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have the same issue trying to update wordpress posts at my Cyrillic [hotel](https://myplanet.bg/hotels/) website .

The short solution is:

After editing the csv file, replace all **"** with **\"** , save the file and open with notepad ++ find and replace all **""** with **"** save the file and you can import it phpmyadmin with the following options:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVaDe.jpg)

( the Replace table data with file is checked if you want to replace the current posts)
the most important is ** Columns escaped with: \ ** - this will help phpmyadmin not give you the *** "Invalid column count in CSV input on line X" *** error

**Here's the whole process step by step:**

1. Export wp_posts table from phpmyadmin .
2. Since I have problems opening it directly with excel - first you should should open it with open Open Office and then copy at excel.
3. When finishing with the edits replace all **"** with **\"** and then save as UNICOD TEXT.
4. Open with notepad ++ and replace all tabs with , and save it as **UTF-8** (if you don't know how you can do this with the regular notepad also)
5. Manually change the extension from .txt to .csv
6. Open with notepad ++ find and replace all **""** with **"** and then save.
7. Import the file with the above setup.

It took me a day of testing but finally I figured this out. The best part is that it works with Cyrillic characters also.